# Combine results from two queries by joining them together

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanted to join the results of these two  queries in one result. I tried to use **Full Outer Join** but I got an error.

```
select MS.TeamID, count(MS.MemberID) as Number_Of_Members
from MEMBERSHIP MS
where MS.TeamID  in
(select TeamID
from FRANCHISE_APP
where Status ='granted' or Status = 'Granted' or Status ='GRANTED')
group by TeamID;
```

```
select T.TeamID, T.TeamName, T.TeamLeaderID
from Team T
where T.TeamID in
(select TeamID
from FRANCHISE_APP
where Status ='granted' or Status = 'Granted' or Status ='GRANTED')
;
```

The desired result:

```
|teamid|teanname |leadername|numberofmembers|
|------| ------- | -------- |---------------|
|T1    | TI      |  Justin  |4              |
|T2    | MT      |  Danny   |3              |
```

Comment: What's your sample data

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: @D-Shih It is not about the data, Im trying to join them together, the two queries work well and give me the results I need, its just the joining process.

Comment: It would help to include the full-outer-join query you tried and the error you got. Sample data would help even more. Why do you want to join those two queries, rather than having a single query that joins the three tables?

Comment: @AlexPoole  is it possible to make it in one query?

Comment: "It is not about the data" However, having the data makes it easy for us to replicate the problem and to know when we have a solution that gets from your input to your desired output. We can easily make up some data where the query gets to your desired output but if it is not the same structure as your data then we have not solved your problem. So, please help us to help you and [edit] your question to include a complete [MRE] and include an example of **your** table structures and data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joining the two queries is fairly straightforward:

```
select coalesce(t.teamid, t.teamid) as teamid,
  t.teamname,
  t.teamleaderid,
  m.number_of_members
from (<query 1>) m
full outer join (<query 2>) t
on t.teamid = m.teamid;
```

which with your queries included is:

```
select coalesce(t.teamid, t.teamid) as teamid,
  t.teamname,
  t.teamleaderid,
  m.number_of_members
from (
  select MS.TeamID, count(MS.MemberID) as Number_Of_Members
  from MEMBERSHIP MS
  where MS.TeamID  in
  (select TeamID
  from FRANCHISE_APP
  where Status ='granted' or Status = 'Granted' or Status ='GRANTED')
  group by TeamID
) m
full outer join (
select T.TeamID, T.TeamName, T.TeamLeaderID
from Team T
where T.TeamID in
(select TeamID
from FRANCHISE_APP
where Status ='granted' or Status = 'Granted' or Status ='GRANTED')
) t
on t.teamid = m.teamid;
```

I've used coalesce because with a full outer join either of the team IDs could be null, so you want to show whichever is not.

> is it possible to make it in one query?

Both queries refer to `franchise_app` - which could be done with joins rather than `in()` - so you could use that as the initial table and then left outer join to the other two tables:

```
select fa.teamid, t.teamname, t.teamleaderid, count(m.memberid) as number_of_members
from franchise_app fa
left join team t on t.teamid = fa.teamid
left join membership m on m.teamid = fa.teamid
where upper(fa.status) = 'GRANTED'
group by fa.teamid, t.teamname, t.teamleaderid
order by fa.teamid;
```

It seems likely that you would always have a team row so that could be an inner join, but you might know otherwise.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e104a14bfb370eab9d4937b748b77885) with some made-up data to get the result you wanted; which for both queries gets:

```
TEAMID TEAMNAME TEAMLEADERID NUMBER_OF_MEMBERS
------ -------- ------------ -----------------
T1     TI       Justin                       4
T2     MI       Danny                        3
```

I've also changed the status check to look for any variation of capitalisation of 'granted'; though using a function there would prevent an index on that column being used. Having different capitalisation suggests a data model problem though - there should be a restriction on the values that are allowed, via a constraint of a relation to another table listing them. But that's a separate issue...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited info given; few changes to the below SQL should work.

```
With A as (
  select 
    MS.TeamID, 
    count(MS.MemberID) as Number_Of_Members 
  from 
    MEMBERSHIP MS 
  where 
    MS.TeamID in (
      select 
        TeamID 
      from 
        FRANCHISE_APP 
      where 
        Status = 'granted' 
        or Status = 'Granted' 
        or Status = 'GRANTED'
    ) 
  group by 
    TeamID
), 
B as (
  select 
    T.TeamID, 
    T.TeamName, 
    T.TeamLeaderID 
  from 
    Team T 
  where 
    T.TeamID in (
      select 
        TeamID 
      from 
        FRANCHISE_APP 
      where 
        Status = 'granted' 
        or Status = 'Granted' 
        or Status = 'GRANTED'
    )
) 
Select 
  A.teamID, 
  B.teamname, 
  B.TeamLeaderID, 
  A.Number_Of_Members 
from 
  A, 
  B 
where 
  a.teamID = B.teamId;
```